# I have a 3 million unique wallet addresses. What is the most efficient way to get the ETH balance and also no.of NFTs each address is holding?

Tags: wallets, nft, balances, query, dapptools

I am looking for an efficient way to query/get ETH balance and also the no.of NFTs belongs to a unique 3 million wallet address.
Any tools or suggestions will be helpful.
Well, I know we can use any indexer APIs to get all details of an individual address. But how can I do it for 3 million addresses? Sending 3 Million requests to get the data is not an efficient way.
So, looking for some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To get the balance you can use this script:

```
from web3 import Web3

# The provider is your connection to a blockchain
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(“PROVIDER_URL”))

#log if we're connected or not
print(web3.isConnected())

#get the balance
#balance is shown in Wei, which is a huge number. Wei is likes 'pennies' in the ethereum world
wallet_address = "0x55c9bBb71a5CC11c2f0c40362Bb691b33a78B764"
print(web3.eth.getBalance(wallet_address))

#balance here is formatted in ether, 
balance = web3.eth.getBalance(wallet_address)
print(web3.fromWei(balance,"ether"))
```

Getting all NFTs isn’t possible because you have a NFT in a specific contract, if you have a list of known NFTs contracts you can query each and every one of them.

Comment: I know how to get balances. I wanted to know, how to do the same for 3 million addresses.

Comment: Well, there is no magic. The database is the blockchain and you need to access it. You can do it with lambdas over cloud but it will cost you